# Subdomain "m." with Wordpress and. htaccess (Conflict in the rewrite rules in the htaccess.)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I do not usually in the habit of posting , because I always find my answer by searching the forums , but today I came across a real problem !

I have a Wordpress install multisite in a subdirectory of my domain. That is to say, it is at **http://mondomaine.com/fr/** .

I wish to make a mobile version in a subdomain "m . " I want my mobile version is available at **http://m.mondomaine.com/fr/** .

My host has created the subdomain m that points to the root of the site.

When I want to access a page from my mobile subdomain redirects it necessarily to the homepage /fr/ .

I tried to change my .htaccess , But nothing could be done , or I have a redirect loop , or I have a 404 page.

I suppose that there is a conflict between the rules , but I really tried and tested lots of solutions and I found nothing conclusive.

The original htaccess generated by Wordpress and located in the directory /fr :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /fr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

.htaccess that I modified:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /fr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mondomaine.com/fr/$1 [L,P]
```

Thank you in advance to those who respond

Comment: Do you have `mod_proxy` enabled?

Comment: Yes, mod_proxy is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mod_proxy` is enabled then move last `m.` rule right at the top, just below `RewriteEngine On` as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mondomaine.com/fr/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it displays a page not found when I go to a mobile version. 

"not Found 
The requested URL /fr/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Just for testing change `P` to `R` and see what happens.

Comment: There is a redirect to the same page without the subdomain m.

Comment: Ok bring back `P` and check error.log for 404 and tell me what exact error message you get there.

Comment: Hello, finally my hoster had not enabled the mod_proxy. Now that it is enabled, I have a "500 Internal Server Error". I always expect the error log with my hosting.

Comment: Hello, I finally exact error: 

[Wed March 26 10:41:08 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler WAS valid for the URL / en /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy of, make safe the proxy Submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Comment: Not sure about this error. You need to check with your server admin for this.